# Reorder a table based on the values of 2 columns sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table with 4 columns: Name (varchar2), building ('A','B','C'), office (number 1-100), sequence(null). The column building can only take three values ('A','B','C') while the column "office" can take any integer value between 1 and 100. The last column starts empty. The distribution of buildings and offices is random (although there will be roughly the same number of entries for each building). The table will not be bigger than 100 entries at any time.

The task is to fill the column "sequence" with numerical values starting by 1, following the criteria:

- The entries should be numbered in such a way that entries with **the same building and office would get consecutive numbers**. Lets call "block" to a series of entries with the same building and office. A block will have consecutive numbers as order
- The sequence of such blocks should follow the pattern A-B-C-A-B-C-... for the value on the column "building" if possible.

As an example

Original table

| Name | Building | Office | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Anna | C | 1 |  |
| Bob | A | 2 |  |
| Charles | A | 1 |  |
| Diana | B | 5 |  |
| Eve | C | 7 |  |
| Frank | B | 5 |  |
| Gwen | A | 1 |  |
| Herbert | B | 4 |  |
| Irene | C | 5 |  |

Expected result (order by order)

| Name | Building | Office | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Charles | A | 1 | 1 |
| Gwen | A | 1 | 2 |
| Herbert | B | 4 | 3 |
| Anna | C | 1 | 4 |
| Bob | A | 2 | 5 |
| Diana | B | 5 | 6 |
| Frank | B | 5 | 7 |
| Eve | C | 7 | 8 |
| Irene | C | 5 | 9 |

Since Charles and Gwen have the same building (A) and office (1) they get consecutive numbers, and the next entry is a block of building B.

Until now I only had to order them by building following the pattern A-B-C-A-...and I have a procedure to perform that ordering. I also have a method to rename the sequence, therefore it would be valid to order the blocks instead of the entries. This means, the following result is also valid

| Name | Building | Office | sequence |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Charles | A | 1 | 1 |
| Gwen | A | 1 | **1** |
| Herbert | B | 4 | 2 |
| Anna | C | 1 | 3 |
| Bob | A | 2 | 4 |
| Diana | B | 5 | 5 |
| Frank | B | 5 | **5** |
| Eve | C | 7 | 6 |
| Irene | C | 5 | 7 |

Answer (score 0):

I have found something that works, but is probably inefficient. In any case, this is what I came up to:

Assume I have a series of procedures that allow to:

- Update an entry in the table: update(register) where register is table%rowtype
- Renumber the sequence: renumbering() that takes all entries in the table with whatever numbering it has and substitute it by 1-2-3-4-... etc

The basic idea is to have on hand a list of the offices for each individual building. This is done via a cursor cur_building_office with parameter building. Then start working only the entries in building A, going through each office and assigning numbers congruent with 1 mod 3 (1,4,7...). All entries in the same office will gate the same number. Continue the same procedure with building 'B' assigning numbers congruent with 2 mod 3 and last for the building 'C' assign numbers congruent with 0 mod 3.

Last step is to renumber the list

```
procedure build_list()
is 
  k  number;
  --
  cursor cur_building_office(c_building in table.building%type)
  is
    select distinct office
    from table
    where building  =  c_building
    order by office;
  
  cursor cur_workers(c_building in table.building%type
                    ,c_office   in table.office%type)
  is
    select *
    from table
    where building = c_building
    and office = c_office;
begin
  -- Assign numbers 1,4,7,... for workers in building A
  k := 1;
  for c_bo in cur_building_office('A')
  loop
    for c_w in cur_workers('A', c_bo.office)
    loop
      --Workers in the same office c_bo.office receive the same number
      c_w.sequence := k;
      update(c_w);
    end loop;
  -- Update the number when changing the office
  k := k + 3;
  end loop;
  
  -- Assign numbers 2,5,8,... for workers in building B
  k := 2;
  for c_bo in cur_building_office('B')
  loop
    for c_w in cur_workers('B', c_bo.office)
    loop
      c_w.sequence := k;
      update(c_w);
    end loop;
  k := k + 3;
  end loop;

  -- Assign numbers 3,6,9,... for workers in building C
  k := 3;
  for c_bo in cur_building_office('C')
  loop
    for c_w in cur_workers('C', c_bo.office)
    loop
      c_w.sequence := k;
      update(c_w);
    end loop;
  k := k + 3;
  end loop; 
  
  renumbering();
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I understand exactly you want to do but I have recreated your table (TEST) and tried some things. I think one of the following queries will five you what you need.
Let me know if anything works or if more manipulation is needed.

```sql
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY BUILDING ORDER BY BUILDING,OFFICE ASC  ) AS SEQUENCE FROM TEST

SELECT *,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BUILDING ORDER BY BUILDING,OFFICE ASC  ) AS SEQUENCE FROM TEST

SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY BUILDING ORDER BY BUILDING,OFFICE ASC  ) AS SEQUENCE FROM TEST

SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY BUILDING,OFFICE ASC  ) AS SEQUENCE FROM TEST

SELECT *,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BUILDING,OFFICE ASC  ) AS SEQUENCE FROM TEST

SELECT *,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY BUILDING,OFFICE ASC  ) AS SEQUENCE FROM TEST
```

Comment: "I think one of the following queries will give you what you need" - which one would that be? I don't see which one follows the 2nd requirement: "The sequence of such blocks should follow the pattern A-B-C-A-B-C-..."

Comment: None of the queries provided will give the correct answer with the A,B,C ordering as required. There is also no explanation, and 7 answers. In future please determine which answer is correct and explain *why*.